# Table variable in Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm new to Oracle and I need to translate my SQL Server stored procedure to oracle. In SQL Server, I have function that returns a table variable.

Executing looks like:

```
Declare @tblTSVal table(stValue varchar(500), itemKey varchar(255), props varchar(max))
insert @tblTSVal(stValue, itemKey, props) 
  select * from dbo.fn_ag_valuesToTable(@tsVal)
```

I write this function in my Oracle database and it's working. But I do not know how to declare a table variable in stored procedure.

Now I'm trying like this:

Declaration:

```
type AGValues as object
(
   stValue varchar(255),
   itemKey varchar(255),
   props varchar(8000)
);
type ValTBL is Table of AGValues;
```

Executing:

```
insert into tblTSVal(stValue, itemKey, props) 
  select * from TABLE(dbMis.fn_ag_valuesToTable(tsVal));
```

That's causes an error:

> Table or view does not exist.

Give me some advice please.

Comment: Is `dbMis.fn_ag_valuesToTable` a function that returns a `ValTBL`?  Is `tblTSVal` a local variable that is of type `ValTBL`?  Is `tsVal` a local variable that you are passing to your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ValTBL is so-called nested table. To load data in it please use BULK COLLECT option.

Example:

```
SELECT * BULK COLLECT INTO tblTSVal FROM TABLE(dbMis.fn_ag_valuesToTable(tsVal));
```

But that is not root of the "Table or view does not exist." error problem. Please check your rights to execute `dbMis.fn_ag_valuesToTable` function.

To use pl/sql function as a table is worth to read about pipelined and parallel table functions.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#ADDCI2140

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but since you're not returning the query results directly as output (ie you're executing a command), what if you wrapped it in a PL/SQL block?

```
BEGIN
  execute immediate 'insert into tblTSVal(stValue, itemKey, props) ' ||
    'select * from ' || dbMis.fn_ag_valuesToTable(tsVal);
END;
/
```

I'm assuming dbMis.fn_ag_valuesToTable is a function.